# Restrict certain calls to a specific subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, subdomain

I'm putting together an API and only want the JSON & XML calls to be accessible from the `api` subdomain.

But in addition to limiting a response format, there are also certain controller actions that I'd want to restrict to that subdomain as well.

So, how can I restrict certain controllers, actions and even response formats to a specific subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict this in the routes like this:

```
match "photos", :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin"}
```

i think that you can also use a proc for `:constraints` or pass a real constraint-class.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I believe you can do what you want through routes.rb, like so:

```
constraints :subdomain => "api" do
    constraints :format => /(json|xml)/ do
        resources :posts
    end
end
```